# SVN diff is not Happening?

Tags: svn, diff

I have  downloaded code from repository consider the code named as code-5.2.1 and code-5.2.2. revision number is same for both codes. I am not able to do svn diff .once i am running cmd :

```
svn diff code-5.2.1 code-5.2.2
```

cursor waits some time and comes back to same position

i tried using revision number  but didn't work out as its same revision no for both

Comment: How did you download the code? svn checkout URL/tags/? A thing like this?

Answer (score 1):

That command just shows you how each of the two projects differs from its base revision. Since you just checked them out, naturally there are no differences whatsoever.

To find out how the two projects differ from *each other*, use

```
  diff -r code-5.2.1 code-5.2.2
```

i.e. the filesystem `diff`, not the svn `diff` subcommand.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get the diff for the local changes you have made in the code? In that case, simply go to that directory. I assume it's code-5.2.1.
Then, simply `cd code-5.2.1` and then `svn diff`.

You can compare two folders if you want as well. This is not for checking the changes record by version control system (svn).
In that case, enter:

```
diff -ruN code-5.2.1 code-5.2.2
```

-u -- Unified diff, which is probably what you need.

from man page,
-r -- Recursively compare any subdirectories found.
-N -- Treat absent files as empty.